# Symbols are lost after conversion from UTF-8 to ISO8859-1 and back to UTF-8

Tags: conversion, encoding, character-encoding, utf-8

I have a file with properties in French.
I would like to convert it to ISO8859-1.
But after conversion, some symbols are lost.
What is wrong?

```
> cat fr.properties
VAR2="élément n’a"
> cat fr.properties | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1 | iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8
VAR2="élément na"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that character present in the ISO8859-1 encoding? [I don't believe it is.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) Which makes this expected behavior.

To be clear: iconv's output in the `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1` must be completely in the ISO8859-1 encoding. It can't leave ANYTHING in UTF-8. So, if there's a character in the input text that can't be represented in ISO8859-1, then iconv drops it.

When you then convert back, there's no way for the `iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8` command to ever know that the missing character existed, so you don't get it on the other end.